# Wordpress wp_ajax returning 0 Object Oriented Plugin using UI-jquery-dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to trigger an action  using ajax inside a dialog with ui-jquery-dialog but the wp_ajax it's always returning cero, my plugin it's all object oriented, I had found information but still not working.

My Code

```
 public function wpsgq_plugin_edit(){

    echo "1";
    die();
}


public function wpsgq_admin_options_page() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');

    $wpdb = DB::getInstance();
    $table_name = $this->prefix . 'plugin';
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    ?>
   <div class="wrap">
        <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
            <h2>My Information in DB</h2>
            <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Text</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Text</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                        <th>--</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                    $i=1;
                    foreach($rows as $row){

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo    "<td class='check-column' scope='row'>".$row->id."</td>";
                        echo    "<td class='column-columnname'>".$row->time."</td>";
                        echo    "<td class='column-columnname'>".$row->name."</td>";
                        echo    "<td class='column-columnname'>".$row->text."</td>";
                        echo    "<td class='column-columnname'>".$row->url."</td>";
                        echo    "<td class='column-columnname'>
                                    <a id='edit_$row->id' name='edit_$row->id' onclick='show_dialog($row->id)'>Edit</a>
                                    <div id='edit-div_$row->id' name='edit-div_$row->id' style='display: none;'>";
                                        $item = $row->id;
                                        ${"view_".$item} = new WPSGQViews;
                                        echo ${"view_".$item}->wpsgq_plugin_view_edit($item);       
                        echo        "</div>
                                </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpsgq_plugin_edit', array( $this, 'wpsgq_plugin_edit' ) ); 
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpsgq_plugin_edit', array( $this, 'wpsgq_plugin_edit' ) );     
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function show_dialog(id){
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        var info = $("#edit-div_"+id);

                        info.dialog({                   
                            'dialogClass'   : 'wp-dialog',           
                            'modal'         : true,
                            'autoOpen'      : true, 
                            'closeOnEscape' : true,
                            'height'        : 420,
                            'width'         : 500,      
                            'buttons'       : {
                                "Edit": function() {

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        async: true,
                                        url: ajaxurl,
                                        data: {
                                            action  : 'wpsgq_plugin_edit',
                                            param   : $("#form-edit_"+id).serialize()  
                                        },

                                        success: function(data){

                                            var $newdiv = $('<div/>');
                                            $("#message").append($newdiv);

                                            $newdiv.html(data);

                                            if(data==1){

                                            }else{
                                                $newdiv.html(data);

                                                $newdiv.dialog({ modal: true, 
                                                    buttons: { 
                                                        Ok: function(){                                                       
                                                            $( this ).dialog("destroy"); 
                                                            $( this ).remove();                                             
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    close: function() {
                                                        $( this ).dialog("destroy"); 
                                                        $( this ).remove(); 
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        },
                                        error: function(data){
                                            $("#message").html("Error: "+data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                "Cancel": function() {
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } 
            </script>
        </div>         
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Any error you can see there will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these two lines out of the `wpsgq_admin_options_page()` function call and into your constructor...

```
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpsgq_plugin_edit', array( $this, 'wpsgq_plugin_edit' ) ); 
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpsgq_plugin_edit', array( $this, 'wpsgq_plugin_edit' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks I made a few changes and I also had an error on the `wp_localize_script` but this change also helped me and now I can continue with my plugin

Answer (score 0):

You must use Jquery ui full version
Or not need more library following 
"./widget",
"./button",
"./draggable",
"./mouse",
"./position",
"./resizable"
Dialog cannot use with only core.

You can find why libraries need
By Following Link
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/dialog.js